# iOS locale notification pop-up doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, popup

I'm a newbie in iOS programming and in my app I've a UILocaleNotification which have to appear at a certain time.

So first I setup parameters :

```
let notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings! = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

    if (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationType.None) {
        var notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound

        // Bouton d'envoi
        var sendAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        sendAction.identifier = "send"
        sendAction.title = "Send"
        sendAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
        sendAction.destructive = false
        sendAction.authenticationRequired = true

        // Bouton de non-envoi
        var dontSendAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        dontSendAction.identifier = "dontsend"
        dontSendAction.title = "Don't send"
        dontSendAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
        dontSendAction.destructive = true
        dontSendAction.authenticationRequired = false

        let actionsArray = NSArray(objects: sendAction, dontSendAction)

        var reminderNotification = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
        reminderNotification.identifier = "reminderNotification"
        reminderNotification.setActions(actionsArray as [AnyObject], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)

        let categoriesForSettings = NSSet(objects: reminderNotification)

        let newNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: categoriesForSettings as Set<NSObject>)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(newNotificationSettings)
    }
```

... and I schedule my notification like that :

```
var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3)
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotification.alertBody = "Hey, inform your contacts !"
    localNotification.alertAction = "Send Message"
    localNotification.category = "reminderNotification"
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

When I try this code, notifs are displaying right in the notification center, but there is no pop-up displayed... 
I searched sources on the net and I don't understand why those examples and tutos are displaying pop-up because I wrote the same code...

Thanks for your help and have a good day !

EDIT : I forgot something : it's the notification center which have to detect an event, and not the locale notification. So I want the addObserver of the notification center to check an event, is it possible in background state ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this line: `localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3)` you want your notification to be triggered 3 seconds later. I assume that the app is still in the foreground when it happens. If it's the case, you will not have a notification popup.

If the app linked to a notification is opened when the notification is received, it has to handle it in your `AppDelegate` to display a custom popup.

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification!) {
        // do your jobs here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just changed "scheduleNotification" with "presentLocalNotificationNow" which make notif appear directly in the notification center. But in fact I want a pop-up to appear, even if the app is running in background (I enabled a background execution mode to keep running the app and that I'm using)

Comment: With your current code the popup should show when the app is in the background as expected. It will not show when the app is open (and there is nothing to do to change that).

Comment: Okay thanks, but the notification isn't displayed when the app is in background. Is there a special thing to do for activate it on the device ? I activated the background execution mode in the project and added it in Info.plist

Comment: No, you don't even have to enable background mode. But since you trigger your notification immediately, how can you test it when it's in background ? Put a "timeIntervalSinceNow: 20", call your method that triggers the function, put your app in the background and wait 15 second to see.

Comment: I edited the question because of my big forgotten error, scuse me